# Create ScalaMock 2.4 ProxyMock without expectations

Tags: scala, scalatest, expectations

Say, my `class Person` collaborates with other classes, `Kettle` and `Teacup`.

`Person` has a method `makeTea()` that should interact with `Kettle` and `Teacup`, each in different ways, in succession, but the order is unimportant.I would like to capture interactions between the `Person` and `Kettle`, and the interactions between `Person` and `Teacup` individually in two separate unit tests (let's call them `testPersonFillsKettleWithWater` and `testPersonPoursBoilingWaterIntoTeacup`)

To test the method `makeTea()` it is not necessary to have `Kettle` nor `Teacup`. When testing for interactions with `Kettle`, any interactions `Teacup` don't matter.

With ScalaMock however if you do not declare expectations on `Teacup` and yet some interactions occur, then `Teacup` throws tantrums about "Unexpected method calls" etc.

In [jMockit](https://code.google.com/p/jmockit/) literature this is called setting 'strict' expectations. I would like to be able to omit specifying every expectation, and just test for certain interactions within one method. So the question is:

**Does ScalaMock support non-strict expectations?**

I'm aware of the `mock stub 'method` syntax, but it is cumbersome to list out all the expectations that I find myself having to list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of functionality is already in the [preview release of ScalaMock3](http://www.paulbutcher.com/2012/06/scalamock-3-0-preview-release/), but not in ScalaMock 2.4 I'm afraid.

I'm not planning any significant updates to the 2.x line. Having said that, what you're looking for shouldn't be too hard to add. Please feel free to [add an issue](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues) and I'll see what I can do.

Alternatively if you fancy having a go your self (take a look at [`ProxyMockFactory`](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/scalamock/ProxyMockFactory.scala) as a starting point) I'd be very happy to accept a pull request that adds this functionality.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure I can live with some boilerplate stubbing for now.